# Add Danger sign in margin of text

Tags: symbols, margins

How can I add a danger sign like the one below? I'm currently using the package `fourier-orns` but the danger sign isn't really good-looking.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Please add a short, compilable code showing us setting your danger sign.  Welcome!

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bclogo

Comment: hello Kurt, I haven't currently any setting (except the fourier-orns package) for the danger sign. The picture I licked is an handout (that I didn't do).

Comment: Do you think I need to use includegraphic with a "real" picture ?

Comment: Welcome, yes, you will need `\includegraphics` if you want to import external pictures. By the way, if you want to reply, put an `@` in front of the name (you can even tab-complete). => @zanzi

Comment: How about the double bend sign from the TeXbook?

Comment: Hi @Johannes_B , thank you for your comment when I was looking up what the bend sign from TexTbook is I found the packcage bclogo with \bcdanger wich is not bad !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sign in the picture come from the package `bclogo` obtain with the command `\bcattention`.

Comment: Well, @touhami has given this solution basically in his comment already